# Simplified expression for Frobenius norm of hessian of matrix function

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

Let $X \in \mathbb R^{n \times d}$ and $y \in \mathbb R^{n \times 1}$ and $u \in \mathbb R^{k \times 1}$. Define the function $F:\mathbb R^{d \times k} \to \mathbb R$ by $F(W) := y^\top \psi(XW)u$ for some twice-differentiable function $\psi:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, and $\psi(A)$ is the matrix with $ij$th entry $\psi(a_{i,j})$.

> **Question.** What is a simplified expression for the Frobenius norm of the hessian $\|\nabla^2 F(W)\|_{Fro}^2$ ?

Comment: I think you meant $\,\psi:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}\,$ and is applied element-wise.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the catch. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}\def\R{{\mathbb R}}\def\v{{\rm vec}}\def\d{{\rm diag}}\def\D{{\rm Diag}}$Let a colon denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = B:A \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|_F^2\\
}$$
Define the matrices
$$\eqalign{
Z &= XW \qquad&\implies\quad dZ = X\,dW \\
P &= \psi(Z)  \qquad&\implies\quad dP = Q\odot dZ \\
Q &= \psi'(Z) \qquad&\implies\quad dQ = R\odot dZ \\
R &= \psi''(Z) \\
}$$
where $(\odot)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product and $\,(\psi',\psi'')\,$ denote the ordinary first and second derivatives of the $\psi$ function.

Write the cost function in terms of the above, then calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
F &= yu^T:P \\
dF &= yu^T:dP &({\rm differential}) \\
  &= yu^T:Q\odot X\,dW \\
  &= Q\odot yu^T:X\,dW \\
  &= X^T\left(Q\odot yu^T\right):dW \\
\p{F}{W}
  &= X^T\left(yu^T\odot Q\right) \;\doteq\; G\qquad&({\rm gradient}) \\
}$$
Next, calculate the differential of $G$.
$$\eqalign{
dG
 &= X^T\left(yu^T\odot dQ\right) \\
 &= X^T\left(R\odot yu^T\odot X\,dW\right) \\
}$$
The Hessian is going to be a fourth-order tensor, so we're stuck.

One way to proceed is to note that the component-wise self derivative of $W$ is
$$\eqalign{
\p{W}{W_{ij}} &= E_{ij} \;\in\,\R^{d\times k} \\
}$$
where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with the $(i,j)$ component equal to one and all others equal to zero.

Then the components of the Hessian ${\cal H}$ can be calculated as
$$\eqalign{
{\cal H}_{ijk\ell} &= \p{G_{ij}}{W_{k\ell}} \\
  &= E_{ij}:\Big(X^T\left(R\odot yu^T\odot XE_{k\ell}\right)\Big) \\
  &= x_i^T\big(r_j\odot y\odot x_k\big)\;u_j\delta_{j\ell} \\
}$$
where the vectors $(x_k,r_k)$ are the $k^{th}$ columns of the $(X,R)$ matrices.

Finally, the Frobenius norm can be calculated for this tensor
$$\eqalign{
\big\|{\cal H}\big\|^2_F
 &= \sum_{h=1}^d\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^d\sum_{\ell=1}^k\;{\cal H}_{hij\ell}^2 \\
 &= \sum_{h=1}^d\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^d\;\Big(x_h^T\big(r_i\odot y\odot x_j\big)\;u_i\Big)^2  \\\\
}$$
**UPDATE**

Since you're only interested in the norm, the $(G,W)$ matrices can be flattened into vectors $(g,w)$. This in turn flattens the Hessian tensor into a matrix (i.e. ${\cal H}\to H$) and allows all calculations to be carried out in matrix notation without *explicit* summations over the components.

For typing convenience, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
I &\in\R^{k\times k}&&\big({\rm Identity\,matrix}\big) \\
A &= I\otimes X\quad\quad&\implies\quad&C = AA^T = I\otimes XX^T \\
B &= \D(b)\quad&\implies\quad&b = \v(R\odot yu^T) \\
g &= \v(G)\quad&\implies\quad&w = \v(W) \\
}$$
Then
$$\eqalign{
dG &= X^T(R\odot yu^T\odot X\,dW) \\
dg &= (I\otimes X)^T\;\big(b\odot\v(X\,dW)\big) \\
   &= (I\otimes X)^TB\;\v(X\,dW) \\
   &= (I\otimes X)^TB\,(I\otimes X)\;dw \\
\p{g}{w} &= A^TBA \;\doteq\; H \qquad\big({\rm Hessian\,matrix}\big) \\
}$$
Now compute the matrix norm as usual.
$$\eqalign{
\big\|H\big\|_F^2
 &= A^TBA :A^TBA  \\
 &= B:CBC \\
 &= b:\d(CBC) \\
 &= b:(C\odot C)b \\
 &= b^T\left(C\odot C\right)b \\
}$$

Comment: The indices and limits in the the summations seem to be messed up. For example $n$ as disappeared; $k$ is used both as an index and a limit of summation; etc.

Comment: I fixed the summations. Thanks for pointing that out. The sum over $\ell$ is missing from the final line, it was annihilated by the delta symbol $\delta_{i\ell}$.

Comment: I updated the answer to utilize matrix notation instead of explicit summations.